# trying to getting sum of running list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

logic: read list using for loop and add all its elements together and, In end print all the iteration value together in the list

**input**

```
lis=[1,1,1,1,1]
ore=[]
for t in lis:
    ore.append(sum(lis[0:lis.index(t)+1]))
    

print(ore)
```

**output**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**expected**

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have no idea why I am getting output like this one, also want to know about the mechanism of this kind of output.
Any possible help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The correct way to iterate over both indexes an items with a list is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), not to try to find the index after the fact; that’s slow, and fails when the list has duplicate elements (like you found out).

   ```py
   for i, t in enumerate(lis):
       ore.append(sum(lis[0:i+1]))
   ```
2. Using `sum` on a slice that grows by one element each time is also inefficient. You know the sum is only changing by the current value in each iteration, so:

   ```py
   s = 0

   for t in lis:
       s += t
       ore.append(s)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is wrong because t represents an item in the lis, not the current index.

Here's the fixed code

```py
lis=[1,1,1,1,1]
ore=[]
for i, t in enumerate(lis):
    ore.append(sum(lis[0:i+1]))

print(ore)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: buddy can please elaborate the mechanism.

Comment: on what mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.cumsum()` from the `numpy` library:

```python
import numpy as np
np.cumsum(lis)
```

returns: a numpy array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`